# Join hibernate search query with criteria query restriction

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm wondering how you would join the following two queries together.

A standard criteria query

```
Criteria result1 = session.createCriteria(Store.class).add(Restrictions.eq("department.name", category));
```

and a FullTextSearch

```
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Store.class).get();
    Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("productTitle").matching(keyword).createQuery();

    // wrap Lucene query in a javax.persistence.Query
    org.hibernate.Query fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Store.class);
    fullTextQuery.setMaxResults(15);
    fullTextQuery.setFirstResult(0);
```

I pass in additional parameters through the URL plus a keyword parameter, I do not want to fully rely on keyword search. Does anybody know how to make these work together?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to use a Filter which can be found here.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.4/reference/en-US/html/search-query.html#query-filter

Answer (score 4):

The Hibernate Search documentation actually discourages using `Criteria` queries combined with full text search queries (except for specifying the fetch type).

> Only fetch mode can be adjusted, refrain from applying any other
>   restriction. While it is known to work as of Hibernate Search 4, using
>   restriction (ie a where clause) on your Criteria query should be
>   avoided when possible. getResultSize() will throw a SearchException if
>   used in conjunction with a Criteria with restriction.

See also http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.4/reference/en-US/html_single/index.html#d0e5722

Comment: do you have any suggestions suggesting a better way to handle these restrictions?

Comment: The best approach is to index all the data you need for your queries and do a single Lucene query. In your case you would also inex the department name and then create a Lucene BooleanQuery. Depending on the use case you could also use a query in combination with a full text filter. Have a look the docs to get more information regarding these features.

Comment: would be nice if they authors told why it is discouraged, or at least point into a direction what the alternative is. Using HQL to filter out data and do a full text search on that is not a bad thought. Instead, it seems the way to go is to use your Lucene query to do the filtering for you instead.

Answer (score 2):

For anybody who may need this in the future, this will demonstrate how to do additional query restrictions with hibernate search.

```
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Store.class).get();
    Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("productTitle").matching(keyword).createQuery();

    org.hibernate.search.FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Store.class);

   Criteria query = session.createCriteria(Store.class)
            .createAlias("department", "department")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("department.name", category));

    fullTextQuery.setCriteriaQuery(query);
    fullTextQuery.setMaxResults(15);
    fullTextQuery.setFirstResult(0);
```

Comment: I think your example is missing the 'setCriteriaQuery(criteria);' part as well