# How to convert Criteria Example Query to Lucene Full Text Query?

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-search

Hi i need help to convert Hibernate criteria query to Lucene Full Text Query, this is possible?, this is my criteria query 
code

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Cliente> example(Cliente cliente){
    Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = org.hibernate.search.Search.getFullTextSession( session );
    Criteria criteria = fullTextSession.createCriteria(Cliente.class);
    Example example = Example.create(cliente)
            .excludeZeroes()
            .ignoreCase()
            .enableLike(MatchMode.ANYWHERE)
            .excludeProperty("idCliente");
    criteria.add(example);
    List result = criteria.list();
    return result;
}
```

https://gist.github.com/ripper2hl/4875f55fefdd8640c507

Similar question -> [Join hibernate search query with criteria query restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309464/join-hibernate-search-query-with-criteria-query-restriction) , but in my case i need only restrictions for criteria query and the query get information in the lucene index, in my code example the query give the information directly from database.

Why i need criteria?, the fields on the entity can be null in the search for this reason i used Example queries --> http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-examples

I need other solution ? (Evaluate manually what properties is null and create the Lucene Full Text Query ).

Comment: Cold you please inline your code instead of adding a link to a gist? Also what exactly are you asking here?

Comment: yes i can edit, convert hibernate criteria query to lucene full text query its my principal problem